# Multiple CollectionView's in VerticalStackLayout in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

If I place more than one `CollectionView` in a `VerticalStackLayout`, only the first one shows up on the screen unless I set the `HeightRequest` for the subsequent ones. They seem to render but for some reason, they're getting pushed way down and I need to scroll down quite a bit before I can see them.

Has anyone tried having multiple `CollectionView`'s in one page in a .NET MAUI app?

What I'm trying to do looks like this:

```
<ScrollView>
   <VerticalStackLayout>

      <CollectionView
         ...>
      </CollectionView>

      <CollectionView
         HeightRequest="150"
         ...>
      </CollectionView>

      <CollectionView
         HeightRequest="150"
         ...>
      </CollectionView>

   </VerticalStackLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Setting the `HeightRequest` doesn't really help me because some of these `CollectionView`'s may produce longer lists and I don't want to set an artificial height limit.

I thought the issue maybe the `<ScrollView>` but because I have multiple `CollectionView`s and in some cases, other controls like `Label` in between, I need the `ScrollView`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: CV's are inherently scrollable because they have a variable size.  They need some sort of size constraint, which a StackLayout cannot provide because it will naturally grow to fit its contents.  You can try to calculate the correct height for each CV at runtime based on the size of its `ItemsSource`.  You could also use a BindableLayout instead of a CV, which might work better if you don't want each individual CV to scroll

Comment: `BindableLayout` maybe a good solution for what I'm trying to do here. Thanks.

Comment: I think this worked before, but since the last update I get the same issue. I can't use `BindableLayout`, because I need the click handlers and selection mode.

I think it's not an elegant solution, but setting the height-request depending on the size of the itemsource might work for me.

I have to calculate different heights for mobile and desktop...